# Laravel and Filament file upload not working on live server

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament

I have a Laravel and Filament based application where file uploading is working perfectly on my local environment. However, when I deploy the application to a live server, the file upload feature stops working. I have tried three different hosting services, but the issue persists across all of them.

Interestingly, there are no error messages in the console or network tab, which makes it difficult to diagnose the issue.

Here is a sample of the code I'm using for file uploading with Filament:

```
use Filament\Forms\Components\FileUpload;

FileUpload::make('attachment')
  ->disk('local')
  ->directory('form-attachments')
  ->visibility('private');
```

I have checked the file permissions on the server, and they seem to be set correctly. I have also tried clearing the Laravel cache, but that didn't solve the issue either.

I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered a similar issue and if there are any potential solutions or workarounds that I could try. Any help would be greatly appreciated!